# going from signed PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE to floating point number in python

Tags: python, numpy

I got a beagleboard i'm trying to program. 
I'm using `PyAlsaAudio` to capture audio and plot it (and do sokme processing on it).

however, this is actually my first forray into python, and into computer audio. Normally i use daq systems and matlab so i've never had to deal with binary (i'm assuming) number.

pyalsa allows me to get outputs in a number of formats but the examples all use `PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE` so i'm sticking to it unless somebody says otherwise.

What i need to learn if how to go from `PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE` to an array of numbers. Should be simple but i haven't found an easy solution.

Thanks for reading, and helping. 
Mustafa

edit :1 
Just wanted to add i tried

```
In [113]: aaa = numpy.fromstring(data)
In [112]: numpy.size(aaa)
Out[112]: 250
```

but the size is wrong because i've assigned 1000 as the period size. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html#pcm-objects), `PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE` is *Signed 16 bit samples for each channel (Little Endian byte order)*. When you use `numpy.fromstring`without the `dtype` argument, it defaults to `float`, which is mapped to `float64`. So your 1000 samples of 16 bits get converted into only 250 samples of 64 bits.

What I think you should do is:

```
aaa = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='<i2')
```

In the data type, `<` states the little endianess, `i` the signed integer type, and `2` the 16 bit, or 2 bytes, length.